# Percentage in fills not showing in the Plot

Tags: plot, ggplot2

I have a bar plot that looks like this:
[image]

I have used the following code for this:

```
ggplot(dffinal, aes(x = Vertical)) +
geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..),fill=Reasons)) +
geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = 
scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) 
+scale_y_continuous(labels =scales::percent)
```

But I want the values of individual fills to be shown inside each fills. This code only shows the total percentages at the top. What should I do?